# Pytest.ini log filename changing with date

Tags: python, pytest, ini, python-logging

When I run my pytests, I want to be able to have the log file change name for when the tests were started. Here is my current ini file

```
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = INFO
log_cli_format = %(levelname)8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s
log_cli_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

log_file = logs/pytest.log
log_file_level = INFO
log_file_format = %(levelname)8s [%(asctime)s] %(message)s
log_file_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

Though I would like to have the format for the log file come out something like...
"logs/test_%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S.log", though using that format in my ini file names the log file the exact string.

Python Version 3.9.6,
Pytest Version 6.2.5

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to do the same thing, and looked around but to no avail. So I came up with this approach but it was somewhat complex.

You need the following things:

- A `pytest.ini` file at project root (which you already have, I believe)
- A Python file named `update_pytest_ini.py` to update `pytest.ini`
- A bash file named `run_pytest.sh` to run update `pytest.ini` and run your `pytests`
- Git Bash or anything that you can use to run `.sh` files

Your project directory could look like this:

```
<root>
|-- logs
    |-- <empty>
|-- pytest.ini
|-- test.py (your tests)
|-- update_pytest_ini.py
|-- run_pytest.sh
```

Content of `pytest.ini` at start:

```
[pytest]
log_file_date_format = %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
log_file = logs/pytest-logs.log
log_file_level = INFO
log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s)
```

Content of `update_pytest_ini.py`:

```
import configparser
from datetime import datetime

# Overwrite log_file filename in pytest.ini with datetime
curr_datetime = datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M_%S")

test_config = configparser.ConfigParser()
test_config.read('pytest.ini')
# Update the string at log_file to with latest datetime
test_config.set('pytest', 'log_file', 'logs/pytest-{}-logs.log'.format(curr_datetime))

with open('pytest.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    test_config.write(configfile)
```

Content of `run_pytest.sh`:

```
if [[ "$OSTYPE" =~ ^msys ]]; then 
    OS=Scripts
else
    OS=bin
fi &&
source venv/$OS/activate &&
python update_pytest_ini.py &&
pytest test.py &&
deactivate
```

You can delete everything before the `python update_pytest_ini.py &&` if you can make sure that you activate your environment before running `run_pytest.sh`. You can run `run_pytest.sh` using:

Git Bash:

```
bash run_pytest.sh
```

Powershell (must have Git installed):

```
sh run_pytest.sh
```

In short, `run_pytest.sh` will:

1. Activate the environment
2. Execute `python update_pytest_ini.py` to update `pytest.ini` with latest datetime at `log_file`. It will change `log_file = logs/pytest.log` to something like `logs/pytest-2022_08_13-13_30_11-logs.log`
3. Execute your tests just like how you do in terminal

You will see that a `.log` file will be created in `logs/`, instantaneously.

**Other approaches that I tried, but did not work:**

1. Running the Python code in `update_pytest_ini.py` before `import pytest` in `test.py`
2. Running the Python code in `update_pytest_ini.py` before instantiate `logging` module in `test.py`

Hope this helps! (Tested on python=3.10.5, pytest=7.1.2)